# Scoring for each row based on matrix in python

Tags: python, bioinformatics, biopython

I have a matrix as follows

```
  0   1   2   3   ...
A 0.1 0.2 0.3 0.1
C 0.5 0.4 0.2 0.1
G 0.6 0.4 0.8 0.3
T 0.1 0.1 0.4 0.2
```

The data is in a dataframe as shown

```
Genes   string
Gene1   ATGC
Gene2   GCTA
Gene3   ATCG
```

I need to write a code to find the score of each sequence. The score for seq ATGC is 0.1+0.1+0.8+0.1 = 1.1 (A is 0.1 because A is in first position and the value for A at that position is 0.1, similar this is calculated along the length of the sequence (450 letters))

The output should be as follows:

```
Genes  Score
Gene1  1.1
Gene2  1.5
Gene3  0.7
```

I tried using biopython but could not get it right. Can anyone please help!

Comment: What is the data type of the matrix? Is it a DataFrame?

Comment: Yes it is a dataframe

Answer (score 3):

Let `df` and `genes` be your DataFrames. First, let's convert `df` into a "tall" form:

```
tall = df.stack().reset_index()
tall.columns = 'letter', 'pos', 'score'
tall.pos = tall.pos.astype(int) # Need a number here, not a string!
```

Create a new tuple-based index for the trall DF:

```
tall.set_index(tall[['pos', 'letter']].apply(tuple, axis=1), inplace=True)
```

This function will extract the scores indexed by the tuples in the form `(position,"letter")` from the tall DF and sum them up:

```
def gene2score(gene):
  return tall.loc[list(enumerate(gene))]['score'].sum()

genes['string'].apply(gene2score)
#Genes
#Gene1    1.1
#Gene2    1.5
#Gene3    0.7
```

Comment: Tried this, I am getting the scores but not the genes and I want this to be assigned to a variable (dataframe) so that I can use it for further analysis. Can you please help.

Comment: You should set gene name as the index to your `genes` dataframe: `genes.set_index("Genes",inplace=True)`.

Comment: I have set the index to genes and I face something weird. Once I run the code, I get the genes and their ids and when I run the same again, I get error as below:

None of [[(0, 'a'), (1, 'a'), (2, 'c'), (3, 'g'), (4, 'g'), (5, 'c'), (6, 'a')....... ]] are in the [index]

Comment: Looks like the second time your genes are in the lower case letters, aren't they?

Comment: Hey! I got it. In addition to making the genes are index, I also kept the indexing done for the tupple. Thank you!

Comment: Can you please suggest me what can be done for this problem - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49481661/scan-the-row-and-find-score-for-every-shift